# SetInterval() not updating innerHTML of an element

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, innerhtml, hoisting

i made a setInterval function that is supposed to update a paragraph every second (technically it is supposed to also change a global variable in the final code, but i figured the problem stands elsewhere).
the innerHTML of the paragraph doesn't update at all

```
<p class="input-text" id="pressed">type something</p> 

let timeLeft = 3;
function update(){ 
    timeLeft -= 1;
    document.querySelector("#pressed").innerHTML = timeLeft;
}
var interval = setInterval(update,1000);
```

i tried to replace `tiemLeft` with other non-variable elements to avoid hoisting, turns out that's not the issue. i dont know that it could be

Comment: You didn't wrap your code inside `<script>` tags.

Comment: Works perfectly fine, given correct HTML. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors. The dev tools provide a **Debugger** tab. Can you find your JS source there? If not, then your JavaScript has not been loaded. [Validate your HTML](//validator.nu).

Comment: As a suggestion, pay attention to what @nilict said, and stop using var. Use let and const